# How to write selenium test case for updating a form

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for the process/steps to follow to edit a form.

User profile page has all the data already entered in it and we want to change the data of the input fields.

SendKeys() append the data in the textfield, I wanted to clear the existing data first , so using clear() now.

Posted the question to know if there is any other way of clearing the field and entering new data .

Comment: 1. To use selenium, you need to know HTML look like. We can't guess it. 2. Try to read some "Hello World" tutorials for selenium to understand how it work. Here is a [link](http://digitalappconsultancy.com/site/learning-selenium-java-hello-world-example/) which could help you. to start.

Comment: Can you share some examples of what you have already written? Share the HTML? This is a really broad question with very little details

Comment: Thanks , I was using sendKeys to enter the data but that was appending the text to that which was already present in the form, I have now used clear() first and then sendKeys to update the information in the form.

Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would achieve it with some data model. 
You can make a profile class for example and make some method that will get the object and overwrite the datas:

```
public class Profile
{
public string name;
public string surname;

public Profile getDatasForEdit()
{
return new Profile()
{
name = "Ritika",
surname = "Arora"
};
}
}

public class ProfileHelper{
    public void fillTheForm(Profile profileDatas)
    {
    formPageObject.nameField.sendKeys(dataModel.name);
    formPageObject.surnameField.sendKeys(dataModel.surname);
    }
}
```

You can add some if statements to fill using just non-null data.
"formPageObject" is the class with Your page object if You have it and "nameField" or "surnameField" are te WebElements defined with locators within this class :)
I hope it helps! : )